# Angular installation failure in Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus)

Tags: installation, angular-cli, ubuntu-16.04

Angular CLI always shows an error while running the installation command and also the `ng` shows *no such command found*. How do I get rid of this problem?

> ```
> shivashish-Inspiron-3521% cd Angular-project
> shivashish-Inspiron-3521% ls
> shivashish-Inspiron-3521% sudo npm install -g angular/cli
> npm ERR! Error while executing:
> npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/angular/cli.git
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Permission denied (publickey).
> npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> npm ERR! and the repository exists.
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /home/shivashish/.npm/_logs/2018-11-25T10_01_17_050Z-debug.log
> shivashish-Inspiron-3521% ls
> shivashish-Inspiron-3521% ng new app
> zsh: command not found: ng
> shivashish-Inspiron-3521% node -v
> v8.13.0
> ```

I run again and now I get this:

```
shivashish-Inspiron-3521% npm install -g @angular/cli
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/shivashish/.npm/_logs/2018-11-25T13_53_57_814Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I changed it to @angular but still the same problem.

Comment: hi, please read carefully my answer; you also need to use `sudo` otherwise you'll have the permission problem

Answer (score 0):

This is because it should be `@angular/cli` instead of `angular/cli`. The correct command is:

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

according to [Step 1: Install the Angular CLI](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart#step-1-install-the-angular-cli)

PS: please don't forget to use `sudo` when installing globally (`-g` parameter) on *linux*

Comment: I changed it , but the same problem arise again.

Comment: hm, thanks; please create an update section to your post in order to print the new logs. My current answer is indeed correct for your current situation so that's why I advice for a separate update section, thank you

Comment: I notice that the updated error logs show that you no longer use `sudo` in the front of the command; that's the permission problem.